# auto_increment to a lower unused number with mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an `old` website and a `new` website... the `old` website had 4500 orders placed on it, tracked by a table with a primary key for the order id.

When the `new` website was launched, it was launched before migrating `old` orders into it. To accomplish this, the `auto_increment` value on the `new` orders table was set to 5000 so any `new` order placed would not collide with an `old` id.

This allows orders to continue being placed on the `new` website, all is well...

Now I'd like to run my import script to bring in the `old` orders into the `new` website.

Is it possible to temporarily lower the `auto_increment` value on the `new` orders table to my desired order id?

**Disclaimer**: This is a migration from a Drupal 5 Ubercart based site, to a Drupal 7 Commerce based site, so I do not (easily) have control over the complex queries involved in assembling the new orders, and cannot simply (AFAIK) supply an order id when assembling an order, because the system always refers to the next available primary key value in the table when creating an order. I can easily take the site offline to run the script, so nothing gets out of sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always run `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;` (or whatever number you want).

The question is: do you *WANT* to?

If you have any records already in the database, it's probably best to insure the *next* auto increment value is *larger* than the maximum already in your database.

Answer (score 3):

For importing the "old" orders you don't need to rely on the autoincrement id-- they already have ids, and you probably want to keep those!

Modify your import script to insert the complete old records into the new table, id and all! As long as the ids don't collide, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks but, part of my disclaimer is I don't easily have control over the mega API and functions that are in charge of all the MySQL statements executed when an assembled order finally gets saved. The e-commerce system's internal functions always seem to use the AUTO_INCREMENT value on the table, and are in no way interested in the order id that I feed to them.